# How to set the different language for asp.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am new to development of asp.net applications... I want to give different language options for the user to choose as he wishes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, consider making your question more specific. This is probably too broad to get a useful answer.

Comment: You may want to poke around here to help reformulate your question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.100).ASPX

Comment: @StingyJack..it is specific to C# and asp.net

Comment: This is a subject that can fit a thousand page book. C# and ASP.NET are not specific enough, and you may want to look into Globalization/Localization concepts to help formulate (or even answer) your question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have all the text for your site set in a language table in your database.  Every piece of text.  Set a unique ID for each languae, 1=English, 2=Spanish, and so on.  Then, when populating the text on your page, rather than calling up the text from a static table, call it up from the Language table for that ID.

Comment: @durbnpoisn..After clicking spanish..how i should convert my application text to to spanish language

Comment: Your text ALL needs to be stored in the database.  Create a table that has columns for ID, Language, name of text string, content of text string.  For each of those entries, you need one for each language.  Then when you call that rows back to populate your web page, you request the ID for the appropriate language.  There really is no way to simply translate the text on your page if it's hardcoded in the HTML.  Take advantage of your database.

Comment: Sorry..I dont need any database..I want something to set in culture